# Pass data type as parameter to function

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I'm using GSON to parse JSON the following way:

```
var obj = Gson().fromJson( json, Array<MyDataModel>::class.java ).toList()
```

I would like to be able to pass the data type via method the following way:

```
fun convert( t : Any ) : Any
{
    return Gson().fromJson( mockedResponse, t ).toList()
}

val model = convert( Array<MyDataModel>::class.java )
```

but I get:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied
```

I also tried *Type* as the argument data type, but the same error persists. How can I pass the DataType to my convert method? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things going on here.

First, the traditional way to pass a type is to pass its [`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html) object (using `::type`) or [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object (using `::type.class`).

So you could declare your function as:

```
fun convert(t: Class<*>): Any
```

But this creates a new problem: `Gson().fromJson()` returns an object of the type you specify.  In this case, it could be anything (hence the `*`), and so the compiler doesn't know whether you can call `toList()` on it.

One solution to this would be to give a type bound, e.g.:

```
fun <T: Collection<U>, U> convert(t: Class<T>): List<U>
```

This specifies that the type you pass must be some implementation of `Collection`, and that it returns a `List` with the same element type.  And because `Collection` has a `toList()` method, it all works.

However, that won't work for your case of passing an `Array` type, as Arrays don't have a `toList()` method.  (`Array` types are a bit awkward in Kotlin.  They're mostly for backward-compatibility with Java; `List`s are better in many ways.)

You could use the above, and use a List type directly.  However, you wouldn't be able to specify the List element type:

```
fun <T: Collection<U>, U> convert(t: Class<T>): List<U> {
    return Gson().fromJson(mockedResponse, t).toList()
}

val model: List<*> = convert(List::class.java)
```

So it's probably better to drop the `toList()` within your function, and not restrict the type at all.  That way, the caller can do any conversion needed, which preserves the element type:

```
fun <T> convert(t: Class<T>): T {
    return Gson().fromJson(mockedResponse, t)
}

val model: List<MyDataModel> = convert(Array<MyDataModel>::class.java).toList()
```

And as a final tweak, we can use Kotlin's other, slightly neater, way to pass types: make them reified.  This substitution is done at compile-time, not run-time, and only works for `inline` functions:

```
inline fun <reified T> convert(): T {
    return Gson().fromJson(mockedResponse, T::class.java)
}

val model: List<MyDataModel> = convert<Array<MyDataModel>>().toList()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're going to have to use generics here:

Something like:

```
inline fun <T, reified R>convert( t : T ) : R {
    return Gson().fromJson(t, R::class.java )
}
```